# Getting error layout not getting displayed as soon as clicked on button

Tags: android

```
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326): Exception while inflating <vector>
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:829)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:303)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:372)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:73)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.widget.CheckBox.<init>(CheckBox.java:66)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.<init>(AppCompatCheckBox.java:58)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox.<init>(AppCompatCheckBox.java:54)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:121)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatBase$FactoryWrapper.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatBase.java:36)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-03 09:19:43.156: E/VdcInflateDelegate(326):  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
```

Comment: what  gradle version you are using ?

Comment: i am using eclipse ide

Comment: i am using eclipse ide how to change the version in it

Answer (score 0):

Do you see **file line #17 tag requires viewportWidth > 0**?